# Why are Ethereum/Solana_provider Javascript files in my Browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, blockchain

In the dev Tools of my Browser <sup><sub>(Brave)</sub></sup> i found a Ethereum_provider.js and a Solana_provide.js file

[Image in the dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbLcC.png)

On other computers there is no such file in the same Browser.

On my Computer VsCode is sometimes laggy, altough i have a pretty fast Pc.

I wonder for what the files could be or if mining is on my Pc or if someone else also has this problem.

That is the ethereum_provider.js:

```js
(function ($Object) {
  "use strict";
  !(function (e) {
    var t = {};
    function n(r) {
      if (t[r]) return t[r].exports;
      var i = (t[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} });
      return e[r].call(i.exports, i, i.exports, n), (i.l = !0), i.exports;
    }
    (n.m = e),
      (n.c = t),
      (n.d = function (e, t, r) {
        n.o(e, t) || Object.defineProperty(e, t, { enumerable: !0, get: r });
      }),
      (n.r = function (e) {
        "undefined" != typeof Symbol &&
          Symbol.toStringTag &&
          Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }),
          Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 });
      }),
      (n.t = function (e, t) {
        if ((1 & t && (e = n(e)), 8 & t)) return e;
        if (4 & t && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
        var r = Object.create(null);
        if (
          (n.r(r),
          Object.defineProperty(r, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }),
          2 & t && "string" != typeof e)
        )
          for (var i in e)
            n.d(
              r,
              i,
              function (t) {
                return e[t];
              }.bind(null, i)
            );
        return r;
      }),
      (n.n = function (e) {
        var t =
          e && e.__esModule
            ? function () {
                return e.default;
              }
            : function () {
                return e;
              };
        return n.d(t, "a", t), t;
      }),
      (n.o = function (e, t) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t);
      }),
      (n.p = ""),
      n((n.s = 1));
  })([
    function (e, t, n) {
      "use strict";
      var r,
        i = "object" == typeof Reflect ? Reflect : null,
        o =
          i && "function" == typeof i.apply
            ? i.apply
            : function (e, t, n) {
                return Function.prototype.apply.call(e, t, n);
              };
      r =
        i && "function" == typeof i.ownKeys
          ? i.ownKeys
          : Object.getOwnPropertySymbols
          ? function (e) {
              return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).concat(
                Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(e)
              );
            }
          : function (e) {
              return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e);
            };
      var s =
        Number.isNaN ||
        function (e) {
          return e != e;
        };
      function u() {
        u.init.call(this);
      }
      (e.exports = u),
        (e.exports.once = function (e, t) {
          return new Promise(function (n, r) {
            function i(n) {
              e.removeListener(t, o), r(n);
            }
            function o() {
              "function" == typeof e.removeListener &&
                e.removeListener("error", i),
                n([].slice.call(arguments));
            }
            m(e, t, o, { once: !0 }),
              "error" !== t &&
                (function (e, t, n) {
                  "function" == typeof e.on && m(e, "error", t, n);
                })(e, i, { once: !0 });
          });
        }),
        (u.EventEmitter = u),
        (u.prototype._events = void 0),
        (u.prototype._eventsCount = 0),
        (u.prototype._maxListeners = void 0);
      var f = 10;
      function c(e) {
        if ("function" != typeof e)
          throw new TypeError(
            'The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type ' +
              typeof e
          );
      }
      function l(e) {
        return void 0 === e._maxListeners
          ? u.defaultMaxListeners
          : e._maxListeners;
      }
      function a(e, t, n, r) {
        var i, o, s, u;
        if (
          (c(n),
          void 0 === (o = e._events)
            ? ((o = e._events = Object.create(null)), (e._eventsCount = 0))
            : (void 0 !== o.newListener &&
                (e.emit("newListener", t, n.listener ? n.listener : n),
                (o = e._events)),
              (s = o[t])),
          void 0 === s)
        )
          (s = o[t] = n), ++e._eventsCount;
        else if (
          ("function" == typeof s
            ? (s = o[t] = r ? [n, s] : [s, n])
            : r
            ? s.unshift(n)
            : s.push(n),
          (i = l(e)) > 0 && s.length > i && !s.warned)
        ) {
          s.warned = !0;
          var f = new Error(
            "Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. " +
              s.length +
              " " +
              String(t) +
              " listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit"
          );
          (f.name = "MaxListenersExceededWarning"),
            (f.emitter = e),
            (f.type = t),
            (f.count = s.length),
            (u = f),
            console && console.warn && console.warn(u);
        }
        return e;
      }
      function v() {
        if (!this.fired)
          return (
            this.target.removeListener(this.type, this.wrapFn),
            (this.fired = !0),
            0 === arguments.length
              ? this.listener.call(this.target)
              : this.listener.apply(this.target, arguments)
          );
      }
      function p(e, t, n) {
        var r = { fired: !1, wrapFn: void 0, target: e, type: t, listener: n },
          i = v.bind(r);
        return (i.listener = n), (r.wrapFn = i), i;
      }
      function h(e, t, n) {
        var r = e._events;
        if (void 0 === r) return [];
        var i = r[t];
        return void 0 === i
          ? []
          : "function" == typeof i
          ? n
            ? [i.listener || i]
            : [i]
          : n
          ? (function (e) {
              for (var t = new Array(e.length), n = 0; n < t.length; ++n)
                t[n] = e[n].listener || e[n];
              return t;
            })(i)
          : y(i, i.length);
      }
      function d(e) {
        var t = this._events;
        if (void 0 !== t) {
          var n = t[e];
          if ("function" == typeof n) return 1;
          if (void 0 !== n) return n.length;
        }
        return 0;
      }
      function y(e, t) {
        for (var n = new Array(t), r = 0; r < t; ++r) n[r] = e[r];
        return n;
      }
      function m(e, t, n, r) {
        if ("function" == typeof e.on) r.once ? e.once(t, n) : e.on(t, n);
        else {
          if ("function" != typeof e.addEventListener)
            throw new TypeError(
              'The "emitter" argument must be of type EventEmitter. Received type ' +
                typeof e
            );
          e.addEventListener(t, function i(o) {
            r.once && e.removeEventListener(t, i), n(o);
          });
        }
      }
      Object.defineProperty(u, "defaultMaxListeners", {
        enumerable: !0,
        get: function () {
          return f;
        },
        set: function (e) {
          if ("number" != typeof e || e < 0 || s(e))
            throw new RangeError(
              'The value of "defaultMaxListeners" is out of range. It must be a non-negative number. Received ' +
                e +
                "."
            );
          f = e;
        },
      }),
        (u.init = function () {
          (void 0 !== this._events &&
            this._events !== Object.getPrototypeOf(this)._events) ||
            ((this._events = Object.create(null)), (this._eventsCount = 0)),
            (this._maxListeners = this._maxListeners || void 0);
        }),
        (u.prototype.setMaxListeners = function (e) {
          if ("number" != typeof e || e < 0 || s(e))
            throw new RangeError(
              'The value of "n" is out of range. It must be a non-negative number. Received ' +
                e +
                "."
            );
          return (this._maxListeners = e), this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.getMaxListeners = function () {
          return l(this);
        }),
        (u.prototype.emit = function (e) {
          for (var t = [], n = 1; n < arguments.length; n++)
            t.push(arguments[n]);
          var r = "error" === e,
            i = this._events;
          if (void 0 !== i) r = r && void 0 === i.error;
          else if (!r) return !1;
          if (r) {
            var s;
            if ((t.length > 0 && (s = t[0]), s instanceof Error)) throw s;
            var u = new Error(
              "Unhandled error." + (s ? " (" + s.message + ")" : "")
            );
            throw ((u.context = s), u);
          }
          var f = i[e];
          if (void 0 === f) return !1;
          if ("function" == typeof f) o(f, this, t);
          else {
            var c = f.length,
              l = y(f, c);
            for (n = 0; n < c; ++n) o(l[n], this, t);
          }
          return !0;
        }),
        (u.prototype.addListener = function (e, t) {
          return a(this, e, t, !1);
        }),
        (u.prototype.on = u.prototype.addListener),
        (u.prototype.prependListener = function (e, t) {
          return a(this, e, t, !0);
        }),
        (u.prototype.once = function (e, t) {
          return c(t), this.on(e, p(this, e, t)), this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.prependOnceListener = function (e, t) {
          return c(t), this.prependListener(e, p(this, e, t)), this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.removeListener = function (e, t) {
          var n, r, i, o, s;
          if ((c(t), void 0 === (r = this._events))) return this;
          if (void 0 === (n = r[e])) return this;
          if (n === t || n.listener === t)
            0 == --this._eventsCount
              ? (this._events = Object.create(null))
              : (delete r[e],
                r.removeListener &&
                  this.emit("removeListener", e, n.listener || t));
          else if ("function" != typeof n) {
            for (i = -1, o = n.length - 1; o >= 0; o--)
              if (n[o] === t || n[o].listener === t) {
                (s = n[o].listener), (i = o);
                break;
              }
            if (i < 0) return this;
            0 === i
              ? n.shift()
              : (function (e, t) {
                  for (; t + 1 < e.length; t++) e[t] = e[t + 1];
                  e.pop();
                })(n, i),
              1 === n.length && (r[e] = n[0]),
              void 0 !== r.removeListener &&
                this.emit("removeListener", e, s || t);
          }
          return this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.off = u.prototype.removeListener),
        (u.prototype.removeAllListeners = function (e) {
          var t, n, r;
          if (void 0 === (n = this._events)) return this;
          if (void 0 === n.removeListener)
            return (
              0 === arguments.length
                ? ((this._events = Object.create(null)),
                  (this._eventsCount = 0))
                : void 0 !== n[e] &&
                  (0 == --this._eventsCount
                    ? (this._events = Object.create(null))
                    : delete n[e]),
              this
            );
          if (0 === arguments.length) {
            var i,
              o = Object.keys(n);
            for (r = 0; r < o.length; ++r)
              "removeListener" !== (i = o[r]) && this.removeAllListeners(i);
            return (
              this.removeAllListeners("removeListener"),
              (this._events = Object.create(null)),
              (this._eventsCount = 0),
              this
            );
          }
          if ("function" == typeof (t = n[e])) this.removeListener(e, t);
          else if (void 0 !== t)
            for (r = t.length - 1; r >= 0; r--) this.removeListener(e, t[r]);
          return this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.listeners = function (e) {
          return h(this, e, !0);
        }),
        (u.prototype.rawListeners = function (e) {
          return h(this, e, !1);
        }),
        (u.listenerCount = function (e, t) {
          return "function" == typeof e.listenerCount
            ? e.listenerCount(t)
            : d.call(e, t);
        }),
        (u.prototype.listenerCount = d),
        (u.prototype.eventNames = function () {
          return this._eventsCount > 0 ? r(this._events) : [];
        });
    },
    function (e, t, n) {
      !(function () {
        if (!window.ethereum) return;
        var e = new (n(0))();
        $Object.defineProperties(window.ethereum, {
          on: { value: e.on, writable: !1 },
          emit: { value: e.emit, writable: !1 },
          removeListener: { value: e.removeListener, writable: !1 },
          removeAllListeners: { value: e.removeAllListeners, writable: !1 },
        });
        var t = !1,
          r = () => {
            t ||
              (console.warn(
                "You are accessing the window.web3 shim. This object is deprecated, please use window.ethereum instead."
              ),
              (t = !0));
          };
        const i = { __isMetaMaskShim__: !0, currentProvider: window.ethereum },
       o = new Proxy(i, {
            get: (...e) => (r(), Reflect.get(...e)),
            set: (...e) => (r(), Reflect.set(...e)),
          });
        $Object.defineProperty(window, "web3", {
          value: o,
          enumerable: !1,
          configurable: !0,
          writable: !0,
        });
      })();
    },
  ]);
});
```

and this is the solana_provider.js:

```js
(function ($Object) {
  "use strict";
  !(function (e) {
    var t = {};
    function n(r) {
      if (t[r]) return t[r].exports;
      var i = (t[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} });
      return e[r].call(i.exports, i, i.exports, n), (i.l = !0), i.exports;
    }
    (n.m = e),
      (n.c = t),
      (n.d = function (e, t, r) {
        n.o(e, t) || Object.defineProperty(e, t, { enumerable: !0, get: r });
      }),
      (n.r = function (e) {
        "undefined" != typeof Symbol &&
          Symbol.toStringTag &&
          Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }),
          Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 });
      }),
      (n.t = function (e, t) {
        if ((1 & t && (e = n(e)), 8 & t)) return e;
        if (4 & t && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
        var r = Object.create(null);
        if (
          (n.r(r),
          Object.defineProperty(r, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }),
          2 & t && "string" != typeof e)
        )
          for (var i in e)
            n.d(
              r,
              i,
              function (t) {
                return e[t];
              }.bind(null, i)
            );
        return r;
      }),
      (n.n = function (e) {
        var t =
          e && e.__esModule
            ? function () {
                return e.default;
              }
            : function () {
                return e;
              };
        return n.d(t, "a", t), t;
      }),
      (n.o = function (e, t) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t);
      }),
      (n.p = ""),
      n((n.s = 2));
  })([
    function (e, t, n) {
      "use strict";
      var r,
        i = "object" == typeof Reflect ? Reflect : null,
        o =
          i && "function" == typeof i.apply
            ? i.apply
            : function (e, t, n) {
                return Function.prototype.apply.call(e, t, n);
              };
      r =
        i && "function" == typeof i.ownKeys
          ? i.ownKeys
          : Object.getOwnPropertySymbols
          ? function (e) {
              return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).concat(
                Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(e)
              );
            }
          : function (e) {
              return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e);
            };
      var s =
        Number.isNaN ||
        function (e) {
          return e != e;
        };
      function u() {
        u.init.call(this);
      }
      (e.exports = u),
        (e.exports.once = function (e, t) {
          return new Promise(function (n, r) {
            function i(n) {
              e.removeListener(t, o), r(n);
            }
            function o() {
              "function" == typeof e.removeListener &&
                e.removeListener("error", i),
                n([].slice.call(arguments));
            }
            m(e, t, o, { once: !0 }),
              "error" !== t &&
                (function (e, t, n) {
                  "function" == typeof e.on && m(e, "error", t, n);
                })(e, i, { once: !0 });
          });
        }),
        (u.EventEmitter = u),
        (u.prototype._events = void 0),
        (u.prototype._eventsCount = 0),
        (u.prototype._maxListeners = void 0);
      var f = 10;
      function l(e) {
        if ("function" != typeof e)
          throw new TypeError(
            'The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type ' +
              typeof e
          );
      }
      function a(e) {
        return void 0 === e._maxListeners
          ? u.defaultMaxListeners
          : e._maxListeners;
      }
      function c(e, t, n, r) {
        var i, o, s, u;
        if (
          (l(n),
          void 0 === (o = e._events)
            ? ((o = e._events = Object.create(null)), (e._eventsCount = 0))
            : (void 0 !== o.newListener &&
                (e.emit("newListener", t, n.listener ? n.listener : n),
                (o = e._events)),
              (s = o[t])),
          void 0 === s)
        )
          (s = o[t] = n), ++e._eventsCount;
        else if (
          ("function" == typeof s
            ? (s = o[t] = r ? [n, s] : [s, n])
            : r
            ? s.unshift(n)
            : s.push(n),
          (i = a(e)) > 0 && s.length > i && !s.warned)
        ) {
          s.warned = !0;
          var f = new Error(
            "Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. " +
              s.length +
              " " +
              String(t) +
              " listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit"
          );
          (f.name = "MaxListenersExceededWarning"),
            (f.emitter = e),
            (f.type = t),
            (f.count = s.length),
            (u = f),
            console && console.warn && console.warn(u);
        }
        return e;
      }
      function v() {
        if (!this.fired)
          return (
            this.target.removeListener(this.type, this.wrapFn),
            (this.fired = !0),
            0 === arguments.length
              ? this.listener.call(this.target)
              : this.listener.apply(this.target, arguments)
          );
      }
      function p(e, t, n) {
        var r = { fired: !1, wrapFn: void 0, target: e, type: t, listener: n },
          i = v.bind(r);
        return (i.listener = n), (r.wrapFn = i), i;
      }
      function h(e, t, n) {
        var r = e._events;
        if (void 0 === r) return [];
        var i = r[t];
        return void 0 === i
          ? []
          : "function" == typeof i
          ? n
            ? [i.listener || i]
            : [i]
          : n
          ? (function (e) {
              for (var t = new Array(e.length), n = 0; n < t.length; ++n)
                t[n] = e[n].listener || e[n];
              return t;
            })(i)
          : d(i, i.length);
      }
      function y(e) {
        var t = this._events;
        if (void 0 !== t) {
          var n = t[e];
          if ("function" == typeof n) return 1;
          if (void 0 !== n) return n.length;
        }
        return 0;
      }
      function d(e, t) {
        for (var n = new Array(t), r = 0; r < t; ++r) n[r] = e[r];
        return n;
      }
      function m(e, t, n, r) {
        if ("function" == typeof e.on) r.once ? e.once(t, n) : e.on(t, n);
        else {
          if ("function" != typeof e.addEventListener)
            throw new TypeError(
              'The "emitter" argument must be of type EventEmitter. Received type ' +
                typeof e
            );
          e.addEventListener(t, function i(o) {
            r.once && e.removeEventListener(t, i), n(o);
          });
        }
      }
      Object.defineProperty(u, "defaultMaxListeners", {
        enumerable: !0,
        get: function () {
          return f;
        },
        set: function (e) {
          if ("number" != typeof e || e < 0 || s(e))
            throw new RangeError(
              'The value of "defaultMaxListeners" is out of range. It must be a non-negative number. Received ' +
                e +
                "."
            );
          f = e;
        },
      }),
        (u.init = function () {
          (void 0 !== this._events &&
            this._events !== Object.getPrototypeOf(this)._events) ||
            ((this._events = Object.create(null)), (this._eventsCount = 0)),
            (this._maxListeners = this._maxListeners || void 0);
        }),
        (u.prototype.setMaxListeners = function (e) {
          if ("number" != typeof e || e < 0 || s(e))
            throw new RangeError(
              'The value of "n" is out of range. It must be a non-negative number. Received ' +
                e +
                "."
            );
          return (this._maxListeners = e), this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.getMaxListeners = function () {
          return a(this);
        }),
        (u.prototype.emit = function (e) {
          for (var t = [], n = 1; n < arguments.length; n++)
            t.push(arguments[n]);
          var r = "error" === e,
            i = this._events;
          if (void 0 !== i) r = r && void 0 === i.error;
          else if (!r) return !1;
          if (r) {
            var s;
            if ((t.length > 0 && (s = t[0]), s instanceof Error)) throw s;
            var u = new Error(
              "Unhandled error." + (s ? " (" + s.message + ")" : "")
            );
            throw ((u.context = s), u);
          }
          var f = i[e];
          if (void 0 === f) return !1;
          if ("function" == typeof f) o(f, this, t);
          else {
            var l = f.length,
              a = d(f, l);
            for (n = 0; n < l; ++n) o(a[n], this, t);
          }
          return !0;
        }),
        (u.prototype.addListener = function (e, t) {
          return c(this, e, t, !1);
        }),
        (u.prototype.on = u.prototype.addListener),
        (u.prototype.prependListener = function (e, t) {
          return c(this, e, t, !0);
        }),
        (u.prototype.once = function (e, t) {
          return l(t), this.on(e, p(this, e, t)), this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.prependOnceListener = function (e, t) {
          return l(t), this.prependListener(e, p(this, e, t)), this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.removeListener = function (e, t) {
          var n, r, i, o, s;
          if ((l(t), void 0 === (r = this._events))) return this;
          if (void 0 === (n = r[e])) return this;
          if (n === t || n.listener === t)
            0 == --this._eventsCount
              ? (this._events = Object.create(null))
              : (delete r[e],
                r.removeListener &&
                  this.emit("removeListener", e, n.listener || t));
          else if ("function" != typeof n) {
            for (i = -1, o = n.length - 1; o >= 0; o--)
              if (n[o] === t || n[o].listener === t) {
                (s = n[o].listener), (i = o);
                break;
              }
            if (i < 0) return this;
            0 === i
              ? n.shift()
              : (function (e, t) {
                  for (; t + 1 < e.length; t++) e[t] = e[t + 1];
                  e.pop();
                })(n, i),
              1 === n.length && (r[e] = n[0]),
              void 0 !== r.removeListener &&
                this.emit("removeListener", e, s || t);
          }
          return this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.off = u.prototype.removeListener),
        (u.prototype.removeAllListeners = function (e) {
          var t, n, r;
          if (void 0 === (n = this._events)) return this;
          if (void 0 === n.removeListener)
            return (
              0 === arguments.length
                ? ((this._events = Object.create(null)),
                  (this._eventsCount = 0))
                : void 0 !== n[e] &&
                  (0 == --this._eventsCount
                    ? (this._events = Object.create(null))
                    : delete n[e]),
              this
            );
          if (0 === arguments.length) {
            var i,
              o = Object.keys(n);
            for (r = 0; r < o.length; ++r)
              "removeListener" !== (i = o[r]) && this.removeAllListeners(i);
            return (
              this.removeAllListeners("removeListener"),
              (this._events = Object.create(null)),
              (this._eventsCount = 0),
              this
            );
          }
          if ("function" == typeof (t = n[e])) this.removeListener(e, t);
          else if (void 0 !== t)
            for (r = t.length - 1; r >= 0; r--) this.removeListener(e, t[r]);
          return this;
        }),
        (u.prototype.listeners = function (e) {
          return h(this, e, !0);
        }),
        (u.prototype.rawListeners = function (e) {
          return h(this, e, !1);
        }),
        (u.listenerCount = function (e, t) {
          return "function" == typeof e.listenerCount
            ? e.listenerCount(t)
            : y.call(e, t);
        }),
        (u.prototype.listenerCount = y),
        (u.prototype.eventNames = function () {
          return this._eventsCount > 0 ? r(this._events) : [];
        });
    },
    ,
    function (e, t, n) {
      !(function () {
        if (!window.braveSolana) return;
        var e = new (n(0))();
        $Object.defineProperties(window.braveSolana, {
          on: { value: e.on, writable: !1 },
          off: { value: e.off, writable: !1 },
          emit: { value: e.emit, writable: !1 },
          removeListener: { value: e.removeListener, writable: !1 },
          removeAllListeners: { value: e.removeAllListeners, writable: !1 },
        });
      })();
    },
  ]);
});
```

<sub>I posted it on stackoverflow because it's related to programming and only programmers would find something in the dev tools.</sub>

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume it happens because Brave has a native wallet integration with Ethereum and Solana.

https://brave.com/1.39-release/